# MyBatis Generator removes useGeneratedKeys="true"

Tags: generator, mybatis

I'm using MyBatis Generator in Eclipse Helios (MyBatis Generator 1.3.1.201101032122)but every time I generate automatically the persistent classes the generator removes the attribute useGeneratedKeys="true".

So for example I have the tag  in my AdresseMapper.xml. After I changed something in my db and I run 'Generate MyBatis Artifacts' this tag is overwritten and useGeneratedKey isn't there anymore...When I remove WARNING - @mbggenerated, there is a conflict between a new generated insert(without the attribute) and the old version...

Could you kindly help me? I didn't find anything in the official doc..

Many thanks
Fabio

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The MyBatis Generator must know which column has generated keys. You can do that using the `generatedKey` tag inside the `table` tag.

Example:

```
    <table tableName="adresse" alias="adresse">
        <generatedKey column="id" sqlStatement="MySql" identity="true" />
    </table>
```